# UI library for Windows Mobile 6

Tags: user-interface, windows-mobile-6

I need some help finding a graphic library for Windows Mobile 6 with a control to answer some quick Yes/No questions.

[Something like what's shown here](http://www.telogis.com/images/mobile/truck-inspection-report.png)

Also, I need to do [something like this.](http://www.telogis.com/images/mobile/hours-of-service.png) 
I don't need to present it the information in the exact same way but that would definitively be a plus.

Thank you very much in advance. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Hello. For the first (Yes/No) I would write my own custom control. For the second I would extend an existing custom control. I am not aware of any WM6 GUI library that would expose both of what you need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way I did it at the end was how josef said, I wrote my own control for the Yes/No answers and I designed a static class to draw over a predefined image with the format already stablished (I just draw the lines indicating what the driving did at a particular time)